# If $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, show that $(AB-BA)(AB-BA)$ is a scalar matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is the set of $2\times 2$ matrices.

> If $A,B\in M_2(\mathbb{R})$, show that $(AB-BA)(AB-BA)$ is a scalar matrix.

I'm a bit stuck with this. Until now I *know*: Matrix multiplication is associative but in general, not commutative. And other basic properties of matrices.

I've tried to do it via the *perhaps* dumb way, that is, working with the matrix elements themselves:

> [image]

And it works, but is there a less cumbersome way? I've tried to write:

$$(AB-BA)(AB-BA)\stackrel{?}{=}\lambda I$$

And multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ to see if something interesting/helpful happens but got nothing. And I've tried to expand:

$$(AB-BA)(AB-BA)$$

But also yielded nothing. So is that the only way to do it or there is some more interesting way?

Comment: Do you know the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: @MichaelBiro No. The book I'm using still didn't introduce it. So I suppose it can't be used (I usually answer the books trying to using only what is given, I guess the authors expect that from the students) - But I'll look for it because I'm curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may split the proof into two steps:

1. Show that $AB-BA$ is in the form of $\pmatrix{x&y\\ z&-x}$ for some numbers $x,y,z$. The exact values of the entries are unimportant, the key is to show that the top left entry is the negative of the bottom right entry.
2. Prove that for every matrix of the form $\pmatrix{x&y\\ z&-x}$, its square is a scalar matrix.